# Parent Activity not receiving Messages from Thread

Tags: android, multithreading

My test app below is roughly based on this [threads tutorial](http://indyvision.net/2010/02/android-threads-tutorial-part-3/) by Cristian Baita.
It works as expected, with the exception that the message sent from myThread's run() method is never received by the MainActivity's handler.

I am passing the MainActivity's handler to myThread in the thread's constructor. I then use that handler's sendMessage() method to send a message back to the MainActivity, but the handler never seems to receive it. Why is this?

Note: I've found using breakpoints for debugging in eclipse is a pain with threads, so I ended up going over the top with Log statments instead to help follow the apps execution.

I've put the full code at the end of this post, but to summarise:

The constructor for the MyThread class takes a handler from the calling activity as shown below.

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {

    // Reference to mainHandler from the mainThread
    private Handler parentHandler;

    // Constructor
    public MyThread(Handler pHandler) {
        parentHandler = pHandler;
    }
```

When I create the thread in MainActivity's onCreate() method I pass it the handler `mainHandler`:

```
myThread = new MyThread(mainHandler);
myThread.start();
```

Then in MyThread's run() method I have:

```
    Message messageToParent = Message.obtain();
    messageToParent.what = 2;
    Log.i("myThread", "About to send message to parent ...");
    parentHandler.sendMessage(messageToParent);
```

The message should then be received by `mainHandler` defined in MainActivity:

```
    public Handler mainHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessages(Message msg){
            Log.i("MainActivity", "Message Received");
            switch(msg.what) {
                case 2:
                    Log.i("MainActivity", "Handled message. msg.what = " + msg.what);
    ....
```

If you watch the LogCat window when this runs, you will see that MainActivity never logs "Message Received" or "Handled message... ". So the message never arrives at it's destination.

**The MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private MyThread myThread;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myThread = new MyThread(mainHandler);
    myThread.start();

    // Message the thread
    Message msgToThread = Message.obtain();
    msgToThread.what = 4;
    Log.i("MainActivity", "About to send message to thread...");
    myThread.getHandler().sendMessage(msgToThread);
}

public Handler mainHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessages(Message msg){
        Log.i("MainActivity", "Message Received");
        switch(msg.what) {
            case 2:
                Log.i("MainActivity", "Handled message. msg.what = " + msg.what);

                // Message the thread
                Message msgToThread = Message.obtain();
                msgToThread.what = 6;
                myThread.getHandler().sendMessage(msgToThread);

                break;
            default:
                Log.i("MainActivity", "Unhandled message. msg.what = " + msg.what);
                break;
        }
    }
};
}
```

**The MyThread class:**

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {

// Reference to mainHandler from the mainThread
private Handler parentHandler;

// Constructor
public MyThread(Handler pHandler) {
    parentHandler = pHandler;
}

// Local handler for messages to this thread
private Handler myThreadHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        switch(msg.what) {

            case 4:
                Log.i("myThread", "Handled message. msg.what = " + msg.what);
                break;

            case 6:
                Log.i("myThread", "Handled message. msg.what = " + msg.what);
                break;

            default:
                Log.i("myThread", "Unhandled message. msg.what = " + msg.what);
                break;              
        }
    }
};


@Override
public void run() {     
    super.run();

    int count = 0;
    boolean keepGoing = true;

    try {

        while(true) {

            Log.i("myThread", "run() method - while loop is ticking ..." + count);

            // some arbitrary conditions to make stuff happen
            switch(count) {
                case 5:
                    Message messageToParent = Message.obtain();
                    messageToParent.what = 2;
                    Log.i("myThread", "About to send message to parent ...");
                    parentHandler.sendMessage(messageToParent);
                    break;
                case 10:
                    keepGoing = false;
                    break;
            }

            if(!keepGoing) {
                Log.i("myThread", "myThread is going to stop");
                break;
            }

            count++;
            sleep(500);

        }

    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("My Log", "Thread Loop Exception - " + e);
    }
    Log.i("myThread", "myThread has reached the end of it's run() method");
}

public Handler getHandler() {
    return myThreadHandler;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realized I misunderstood what we are doing when we write the `handleMessage()` method for our handler.

I thought we were writing a new method for the handler, so I named it something slightly different `handleMessages()` (notice the plural).

In fact what we are doing is overriding one of the handler's existing method.

In the sample code I was following, Cristian Baita does not use an `@Override` statement before his `handleMessage()` method. This is fair enough, since `@Override` is only a convenience for you and your compiler to highlight bugs. Embarrassingly it is my fault for assuming that because `@Override` wasn't there, we weren't overriding anything. Hopefully this slip up will help some others in their learning curve.

BTW: I would still thoroughly recommend Cristian Baita's 3 thread tutorials, as they are very clearly explained and easy to follow. The problem was mine, in making assumptions!

Answer (score 0):

From an initial look, it might be because your parent handler is private. change it to public and try once!

Comment: Unfortunately that does not fix the problem, but you are correct it should be public. I've now edited the post to suit. Thank you.